# Is there a way to restrict sending an email to a pre-defined destination only?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, email

I would like to send some info from within the app per email - but restruct the recipient list.

I know when sending emails the standard email-dialog opens. However, is there a solution anyway? Possibly somehow intercepting the "Send" Btn and at least check the recipient list.

Comment: only if you do it on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do this. iOS requires that the user controls the final setup of an outbound email for security/trust reasons. If you're asking for undocumented workarounds, someone (not me) might know one, but your app won't be App Store-eligible if you find one.

As commenter @Rog says, if you send email via your own server, you can do this however you want without Apple's restrictions.